# I upgraded my desktop to Kubuntu 21.04 and installed an AMD 6800XT; why am I now getting worse performance?

Tags: kde, games, amd-graphics, amdgpu, 21.04

I had previously been running Kubuntu 20.10 with an AMD RX580 and everything worked just fine. I upgraded to 21.04 and installed the 6800XT (I did not test gaming performance after the OS upgrade before upgrading the card). My frames in Valheim had previously been ~45 with lots of variance but now they are pretty much stuck at 30, sometimes going slightly above or below. I thought the open source/default drivers in 21.04 were supposed to support this card. What am I missing?

I am running a Ryzen 3900X as my CPU with 32GB RAM on a 2K resolution monitor so nothing else *should* be bottlenecking as best I am aware. The only hardware change was the 6800XT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by performing a clean re-install of my system. Apparently some unknown config from before was causing problems.